# ReactJS fetch - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

How can I get this to fetch the `temp` and `icon` from https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text=%22auckland%22)&format=json&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys?

This is what I have so far but getting an `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` when trying to fetch data from Yahoo Weather. I have looked at other solutions for the `'map' of undefined` but none seem to help my problem.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Weather extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            temperature: [],
        };
    }
    componentWillMount() {

        fetch('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22auckland%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys')
            .then(results => {
                return results.json();
            }).then(data => {
                var temperature = data.results.map((temps) => {
                    return(
                        <span key={temps.results}>
                            {temps.condition.temp}
                        </span>
                    )
                })
                this.setState({temperature: temperature});
                console.log("state", this.state.temperature);
            })
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <div id="weather">
                <span>{this.state.temperature} &deg;C | {this.state.temperature} &deg;F</span>
            </div>
        )
    }    
}

export default Weather
```

Comment: `'map' of undefined` means `data.results` is undefined. Try logging that.

Comment: You should fetch on `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Thank you @EricNa. That makes perfect sense but still not finding the data.

Comment: @BrahmaDev. Cheers, any ideas where it is failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` is an object with a structure like this:

```
{
query:
  count: 1
  ...
  results: {
    channel: {
      astronomy: { }
      atmosphere: { }
      ...
```

So to access the `results` property, you would have to access `data.query.results`:

`const results = data.query.results`

but then there are two problems: `results` is an object, not an array, so you can't `.map` it, and also, there doesn't seem to be a `condition` key in it.

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

```js
fetch('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22auckland%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys')
  .then(results => {
  return results.json();
}).then(data => {
  const temp = data.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
  console.log(temp);
});
```

Comment: Yes... that's what I missed. Thank you - any ideas how I can get the value of `query > results > channel > item > condition > temp`?

Comment: Sure, just use the dot operator. Edited

Comment: Cheers for your help

Answer (score 3):

As I can see from the link you have provided, the structure of the response is a bit difference.

You expect it to be:

```
{ results: any }
```

But in reality it is:

```
{ query: { results: any } }
```

Comment: Cheers Daniel. Yes, I just realised that - any idea how I could adapt to get the `temp`?